# PHP getimagesize empty output

Tags: php, getimagesize

```
<?php
$URL="http://cor-forum.de/forum/images/smilies/zombie.png";
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($URL);

echo 'width: '.$width.'<br>
height: '.$height;
?>
```

This results in the following output:

```
width:
height:
```

EDIT and I get the following warning:

> Warning:
> getimagesize(http://cor-forum.de/forum/images/smilies/zombie.png):
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
> /html/test.php on
> line 6

--whereas it displays the right values if I use another picture like

```
$URL='http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://google.com?defaulticon=1pxgif';
```

EDIT:
I'd like to enable the inclusion of external images in a forum, but I want to check their size first.
So, what can I do to get the size of an image, whose server is "blocking me"?

EDIT:
allow_url_fopen is set to ON, yes.

Comment: is `allow_url_fopen` set ?

Comment: Turn on proper error reporting.

Comment: tried it again, still different outputs. 
I was able to get a warning now, though. Edited the starting post. What does that mean? regards

Comment: @Blauhirn seems like the server is blocking you.

Comment: Looks like the domain is trying to ban hotlinking to images (which can hit bandwidth pretty hard). Why don't you use your own image?

Comment: that doesn't sound good. I'd like to enable the inclusion of external images in a forum, but I want to check their size first.
What can I do to get the size of an image, whose server is "blocking me", anyway? (gonna write the same sentence in the starting post)

Comment: @Blauhirn It depends on how the server is blocking you... most servers use your http referer as an indicator.

Comment: Inner URL needs `urlencode()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faking the HTTP referer field seems to work on this one:

```php
<?php
function getimgsize($url, $referer = '')
{
    $headers = array(
                    'Range: bytes=0-32768'
                    );

    /* Hint: you could extract the referer from the url */
    if (!empty($referer)) array_push($headers, 'Referer: '.$referer);

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    $return = array(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));

    imagedestroy($image);

    return $return;
}

list($width, $heigth) = getimgsize('http://cor-forum.de/forum/images/smilies/zombie.png', 'http://cor-forum.de/forum/');

echo $width.' x '.$heigth;
?>
```

Source of [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4635991/3398739)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your having problem with mentioned URL can you try the below code
I have not done anything just changed the URL,

```
URL = "http://forums.phpfreaks.com/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-68615.jpg";
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($URL);
echo 'width: ' . $width . '<br>height: ' . $height;
```

Comment: yes that works, the problem lies definately in the URL

Comment: I gone through that site and and tried all the url nothing is working actually its forbidden to access by other means.

Answer (score -3):

set PHP memory limit to maximum 256 Mb to fix it